# Solidity: checking for number match

Tags: solidity

I have the following array of `uint8`s in Solidity:

```
[8, 1253, 54, 777, 553]
```

There needs to be a function that gets one input `uint8` number and checks to see whether or not the input number matches with any of the `uint8` numbers in the array above.

What would be the best way to implement such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a `for` loop:

```
function check(uint8 n) public returns (bool) {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == n) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But if you're concerned about gas costs, have the client tell you exactly where in the array the number is. (The client can find this position offline.)

```
function check(uint8 n, uint256 position) public returns (bool) {
    return arr[position] == n;
}
```